# How you configure the keyboard?

Tags: settings

I have tirer to configure elementary keyboard in ita but does not go!
How to set up the keyboard in italian?

How can i do ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried from Keyboard settings in System Settings or some other way?

Go to System Settings->Keyboard->Layout, then press small plus icon (+) in bottom left corner and add Italian keyboard. Change the layout and try typing, it should work.